# Python nested package issue

Tags: python, nested, package

I have been trying to fix this for a bit, and I must be missing something basic here (forgive me, I am relatively new to Python development):

I have a package structure like this:

```
base
|
 -->util
    __init__.py
    Class1.py
    Class2.py
__init__.py
Main.py
```

My classes are fairly benign:

```
class Class1(object):

    def __init__(self):

    # some methods...


class Class2(object):

    def __init__(self):

    # more methods...
```

In the `Main.py`, I have:

```
import utils

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c1 = utils.Class1()
    c2 = utils.Class2()
```

My `PYTHONPATH` is setup to include `src`, `src\base`, and `src\base\utils`. But, Python gives me this error when trying to run `Main.py`:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Class1'
```

Has someone encountered this, and do you know how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Do not name files as the classes inside. Thats a bad habbit as you don't know if sth is a class or a package. Use lowercase-only names for modules (files).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a little different than Java.  In java each file is usually a class, in python, each file is a module.  Given the scenario you describe here, you would do:

```
import utils.Class1
import utils.Class2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c1 = utils.Class1.Class1()
    c2 = utils.Class2.Class2()
```

You could do a number of things here.  For example, you could have a module called "resources" like this:

```
base ->
    utils ->
        resources.py
```

which contains both Class1 and Class2.  Then you could do something like:

```
import utils.resources


c1 = utils.resources.Class1()
```

etc.  But the key is that classes != files in python

Comment: Thanks! That hit the nail on the head :) I was incorrectly leveraging previous OO knowledge :)

Answer (score 0):

did you import your classes into the **main**.py of the utils module?
just add to utils/**init**.py:

```
from Class1 import Class1
from Class2 import Class2
```

then in your main.py, "import utils" will import those files as utils.Class1 etc